# custom lists with features

Tags: lists, fbox

Here I'm providing the most basic possible example of a custom `\list`. I would like either the boxes to be visible, or draw boxes of the same size as those used by the engine I'm using, which is luatex. This is for both understanding how `\list` works and see how items are spaced. Also I would like to see how I can make this environment so that, in my actual list ("first item", "second item",...) I do not need to insert `\item`. What is the purpose of `\item\relax` here? This code produces the same result without it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[verbose,hmargin=30mm,
                    vmargin=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe,fontsize}     %% <- show boundary of text area

\newenvironment{customlist}
{
  \list{--} {}
}
\item\relax
{
  \endlist
}

\changefontsize{10}
\begin{document}
\begin{customlist}
\item first item
\item second item
\end{customlist}
\end{document}
```

Here is how I'm expecting the output with visible boxes. I did with lowriter.
[image]